# How to delete records from a sql database where Variable = Condition

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
self.cursor.execute('DELETE FROM IllnessesView WHERE '+CurrentSymptom+' = 0.0')
```

I have the above line, where self.cursor is the database cursor. The aim is to delete records from the table IllnessesView where the contents of the column which is named the same as the variable CurrentSymptom is equal to 0.0 in any rows.

I previously tried using (?) for the CurrentSymptom part but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is the name of the column the same as the *name* of the variable, or as the *value* of the variable?

Comment: The name of the column is the same as the value of the variable.

Comment: Common things to check: Does the query work if you connect to your database by hand? Do you have one of the common floating point errors going on (column not _really_ = 0.0)? Can you execute other queries in the program?

Comment: I tried the same command on a similar setup and it worked.

Comment: Think I've spotted it now, only 0.5 is really 0.5, the 0.0 and 1.0's are just 0's and 1's.

Comment: Are you trying to DELETE from a **view** ?

Comment: It's not a view per say as I didn't know how to create one, but it's a table created using the statement CREATE TABLE IllnessesView as SELECT * FROM OtherTable

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = 0.0
c.execute('DELETE FROM IllnessesView WHERE CurrentSymptom=?', (data,))
```

I think this should work

Make sure the parameter uses the comma, to make it a python tuple.